# Heroku + Apartment: Apartment::FileNotFound: /app/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, apartment-gem

I'm building a SAAS platform with heroku and Rails. For these, I'm managing the tenant with `apartment gem`.

In my local development this found without issues, but when I tried to use into heroku appear the next error:

> /app/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet

This error is produced it when run the next command:

> Apartment::Tenant.create('foo_schema')

I'm going to write the main steps to setting up a heroku with subdomains + apartment configuration.

1. Setting up a wildcard domain (This configuration it's ok).
2. I'm using `postgresql` in `production` and `development`
3. Setting up `apartment.rb` file into `initializer` directory.

my `apartment.rb`

```
require 'apartment/elevators/subdomain'

Apartment.configure do |config|
  config.excluded_models = %w{Account Company App Acteco Country Currency Price}
  config.tenant_names = lambda { Company.pluck(:slug) }
  config.use_schemas = true
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before Warden::Manager, Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Did you try running db:migrate? there are some posts with the same issue which suggest to run this task as a workaround.
https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/2y4bdt/how_to_implement_tdd/ https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/331

Comment: Do you have a working app currently on Heroku?  Do you have the DB configured on Heroku? Have any migrations been run there? Are you deploying with `git push heroku master` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `db/schema.rb` to your repository and push again?

Comment: hahahaha, I made a rookie's mistake. I had my schema into `.gitignore` file.

Thanks you.